# Trigger function and open URL at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, anchor, counter

I am creating a counter which counts the number of clicks made to an anchor tag. I also need the URL to be opened at the same time. I tried the below code. The page is redirected before the function executes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var $res = $('#counter').text($.cookie('link-count') || 0)
    
    $('a').click(function () {
        var count = parseInt($.cookie('link-count'), 10) || 0;

        count++;
        if (count > 10) {
            $(this).attr("href", "https://www.yahoo.com");
        }
        $.cookie('link-count', count);
        $res.text(count);
        location.href = $(this).attr("href");
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console? Have you included the jQuery.cookie plugin? You might find [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) useful.

Comment: When I use `href="#"` , the function works but I want the url also to be opened. No, I don't get any errors

Comment: yes try `click(function (e) { e.preventDefault()` and then once you are done with manipulation use `location.href = $(this).attr("href")` to goto target site

Comment: No it is not working. The URL is not opening

Comment: also try `mousedown` instead of `click`

Comment: The URL is not opening? That sounds like a different problem than the one stated in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var linkCount;
$(document).ready(function () {
 var $res = $('#counter').text(linkCount || 0)
    
   $('a').click(function (e) {
      
        e.preventDefault();
      
        var count = parseInt(linkCount) || 0;

        count++;
        if (count > 10) {
            $(this).attr("href", "https://www.yahoo.com");
        }
        linkCount = count;
        $res.text(count);
        location.href = $(this).attr("href")
      
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

Comment: due to security concerns cant use cookies or localStorage, so simulated with global variable